# Datatables: Create a footer on the fly

Tags: datatables

In my project, the number of columns in main table depends on the user settings and I get it from AJAX to dataTable directly. Several of these columns show different amounts (eg pre-price, final-price, etc.). Now, I have a task to calculate these pices to total sums in the footer.

I already know in which columns what amounts and the ordinal number of these columns for a every user. The simplest thing left —  to put these sums in the footer. To do this, I first need to create the required number of footer columns. Simple task, but!

I use a drawCallback method *:

```
drawCallback { 
 string = innerHTML(needNode).repeat(x_times)
 ...
}
```

...and my footer is works.
Then I calculated the page total and I did

```
window.setTimeout(function(){
 $( api.column( columnNumber ).footer() ).html(pageTotal);
},3000);
```

...but I didn't see any result in empty footer...
What am I doing wrong?

*I cannot use the footerCallback method, because it contain no required object for counting columns.

**If I create a footer manually in HTML, then the right result will be displayed in the correct column. But the footer will be displayed **twice**: my "tfoot" and  automatically created table "dataTables_scrollFoot".

I used the setTimeout() for enough time to create the footer. It works, but does no need effect :(

Help me please. Any help would be appreciated.

[image]
...........
[image]